# Second Like in Find Query

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, typeorm

How to use second `LIKE` in typeorm `find` query? I try like below, but not work and always return empty array

```
        return await this.conn.getRepository(Article).find({
            where: {
                body: Like(`%${query}%`),
                //title: Like(`%${query}%`), //NOT WORK WITH SECOND
            },
            order: {
                lastUpdate: 'DESC'
            },
            relations: ['author']
        });
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want your `where` condition to use `AND` or `OR` -- currently the way you have it constructed will result in an `AND` condition between the two `Like` tests.

Comment: can you show example?

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md -- find the code example labeled: **Querying with OR operator**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make a lot assumptions about your data and use case.

I suspect that the problem you are having has to do with the boolean operation that gets generated by TypeORM for your `where` condition(s).

Based on the way you have specified your request the resulting boolean operation is an `AND`.  This means it will only return TRUE if both `body` AND `title` contain the search string.

I suspect this is NOT what you intended.  I am assuming that what you really want is for the `where` to return TRUE if `body` or `title` **or both** contain the search string.

If all my assumptions are all correct, then you should be able to get the result you want by changing your request to the following:

```js
return await this.conn.getRepository(Article).find({
    where: [
        {body: Like(`%${query}%`)},
        {title: Like(`%${query}%`)} 
    ],
    order: {
        lastUpdate: 'DESC'
    },
    relations: ['author']
});
```

Using this form of the request should result in a `where` clause that use an `OR` operator between the two `Like` tests.